# Python script on Raspberry Pi slows over time

Tags: python, performance

I'm fairly new to Python and this is a pretty simple script.  It runs well but, slows over time.  I'm using the Pi 4 fitted with the Automation Hat.  Also, I have a MIDI to USB interface.  The intent is to switch relays on the HAT corresponding to MIDI commands received.

When the script starts it run perfectly.   Over time, it gradually slows.

Since I'm a bit of a newbie, I'm sure this could be written more elegantly but still, I don't see anything that would be obviously slowing the script...

```
from guizero import App, TextBox, PushButton, Text, Combo
from guizero import App, Drawing
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature


import pygame, pygame.midi
import automationhat
import time
automationhat.light.power.write(0)        
automationhat.relay.one.write(0)
automationhat.relay.two.write(0)
automationhat.relay.three.write(0)

pygame.midi.init()


app = App(title="TwiggyBlues", bg = "white", height=230, width=325)

MidiChnl = Combo(app, selected="MIDI 5", options=["MIDI 1", "MIDI 2", "MIDI 3", "MIDI 4", "MIDI 5", "MIDI 6", "MIDI 7", "MIDI 8"],)
MidiChn = (MidiChnl.value)



drawing = Drawing(app,height=150, width=305)

REVERB = drawing.oval(20, 20, 45, 45, color="black")

SLAP = drawing.oval(100, 20, 125, 45, color="black")

DISTORTION = drawing.oval(180, 20, 205, 45, color="black")

COMP = drawing.oval(260, 20, 285, 45, color="black")

drawing.text(5, 75, "REVERB", color="black",size=10)

drawing.text(95, 75, "SLAP", color="black",size=10)

drawing.text(150, 75, "DISTORTION", color="black",size=10)

drawing.text(255, 75, "COMP", color="black",size=10)

reverbstat = automationhat.input.one.read()
slapstat = automationhat.input.two.read()
diststat = automationhat.input.three.read()
compstat = automationhat.analog.one.read()

print("compstat ", compstat)



#######MIDI INTERFACE##############

inp = pygame.midi.Input(3,100)


def reverb_tog():
   
    automationhat.light.power.write(1)          
    automationhat.relay.one.on()
    #drawing = Drawing(app,grid=[40,10])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    automationhat.relay.one.off()
    automationhat.light.power.write(0)
   
def slap_tog():
   
    automationhat.light.power.write(1)          
    automationhat.relay.two.on()
    #drawing = Drawing(app,grid=[40,10])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    automationhat.relay.two.off()
    automationhat.light.power.write(0)
   
def dist_tog():
   
    automationhat.light.power.write(1)          
    automationhat.relay.three.on()
    #drawing = Drawing(app,grid=[40,10])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    automationhat.relay.three.off()
    automationhat.light.power.write(0)
   
def comp_tog():
   
    automationhat.light.power.write(1)          
    automationhat.output.one.on()
    #drawing = Drawing(app,grid=[40,10])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    automationhat.output.one.off()
    automationhat.light.power.write(0)


def midiloop():
    reverbstat = automationhat.input.one.read()
    slapstat = automationhat.input.two.read()
    diststat = automationhat.input.three.read()
    compstat = automationhat.analog.one.read()
    cpu = CPUTemperature()
    print(cpu.temperature)
    if MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 1":
        chnl = 192
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 2":
        chnl = 193
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 3":
        chnl = 194
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 4":
        chnl = 195
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 5":
        chnl = 196
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 6":
        chnl = 197
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 7":
        chnl = 198
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 8":
        chnl = 199
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 9":
        chnl = 200
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 10":
        chnl = 201
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 11":
        chnl = 202
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 12":
        chnl = 203
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 13":
        chnl = 204
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 14":
        chnl = 205
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 15":
        chnl = 206
   
    elif  MidiChnl.value == "MIDI 16":
        chnl = 207
   
   
    #print("MIDI ", chnl)
     
    if reverbstat>0:
       REVERB = drawing.oval(20, 20, 45, 45, color="blue")
    elif reverbstat<1:
        REVERB = drawing.oval(20, 20, 45, 45, color="black")
       
    if slapstat>0:
       SLAP = drawing.oval(100, 20, 125, 45, color="green")
    elif slapstat<1:
        SLAP = drawing.oval(100, 20, 125, 45, color="black")
       
    if diststat>0:
       DISTORTION = drawing.oval(180, 20, 205, 45, color="red")
    elif diststat<1:
        DISTORTION = drawing.oval(180, 20, 205, 45, color="black")
       
    if compstat>2:
       COMP = drawing.oval(260, 20, 285, 45, color="yellow")
    elif compstat<2:
        COMP = drawing.oval(260, 20, 285, 45, color="black")
       
       
       
 
   
    read = inp.read(100)
    for event in read:        
        ((status,data1,data2,data3),timestamp) = event
        MIDI_Cmd = (data1)+1
        if status == chnl and MIDI_Cmd == 1:
           

           
            reverbstat = automationhat.input.one.read()
            print("Reverb Status ", reverbstat)          
            print(MIDI_Cmd,' received')
            if reverbstat<1:
                reverb_tog()
           
        elif  status == chnl and MIDI_Cmd == 10:
           
            reverbstat = automationhat.input.one.read()
            print("Reverb Status ", reverbstat)          
            print(MIDI_Cmd,' received')
            if reverbstat>0:
                reverb_tog()
               
        if status == chnl and MIDI_Cmd == 2:
           
           
            slapstat = automationhat.input.two.read()
            print("Slap Status ",slapstat)          
            print(MIDI_Cmd,' received')
            if slapstat<1:
                slap_tog()
               
        elif  status == chnl and MIDI_Cmd == 20:
           
           
            slapstat = automationhat.input.two.read()
            print("Slap Status ",slapstat)          
            print(MIDI_Cmd,' received')
            if slapstat>0:
                slap_tog()
               
               
        if status == chnl and MIDI_Cmd == 3:
           
           
            diststat = automationhat.input.three.read()
            print("Dist Status ",diststat)          
            print(MIDI_Cmd,' received')
            if diststat<1:
                dist_tog()
               
        elif  status == chnl and MIDI_Cmd == 30:
           
           
            diststat = automationhat.input.three.read()
            print("Dist Status ",diststat)          
            print(MIDI_Cmd,' received')
            if diststat>0:
                dist_tog()
               
        if status == chnl and MIDI_Cmd == 4:
           
           
            compstat = automationhat.analog.one.read()
            print("Dist Status ",diststat)          
            print(MIDI_Cmd,' received')
            if compstat<1:
                comp_tog()
               
        elif  status == chnl and MIDI_Cmd == 40:
           
           
            compstat = automationhat.analog.one.read()
            print("Dist Status ",diststat)          
            print(MIDI_Cmd,' received')
            if compstat>3:
                comp_tog()

       
#######END MIDI INTERFACE##############
           
Rverb = PushButton(app, text="VERB", align="left", padx=20, command=reverb_tog, width=5)
Slap = PushButton(app, text="SLAP", align="left", padx=20, command=slap_tog, width=5)
Dist = PushButton(app, text="DIST", align="left", padx=20, command=dist_tog, width=5)
Comp = PushButton(app, text="COMP", align="left", padx=20, command=comp_tog, width=5)


app.repeat(100, midiloop)



app.display()
```

Comment: Try installing `htop` and watching the memory size to see if it is growing over time - a common cause of slowdown.

Comment: I assume that every time you execute a line such as: `REVERB = drawing.oval(20,...` you are creating another new `oval` which accumulate over time.

Comment: Thank you, Yep...  Adding, drawing.clear()  to the top of the midiloop function fixed it.